# Concurrency trouble (The senate bus)

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, infinite-loop, semaphore

Hi every one I have to code a senate bus problem like code in java. I'm new in the java word and concurrency in general.
Here we must use concurrency and semaphore to resolve it.

We have a bus traveling between 5 stations and repeat the cycle, the bus can
take 50 persons , at each station random number of persons get off the bus and random number of person get on the bus.

This is what i have done for the moment

```
class Assignment2 {
    public static Station current_station;

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        // create our random number of passenger
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        int NbrPassengers = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);

        Passenger[] passengers = new Passenger[NbrPassengers];

        List<Station> stationList = new LinkedList<Station>();

        Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(50);
        Bus bus = new Bus(semaphore, stationList);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Station e = new Station(bus, i, true);
            stationList.add(e);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < passengers.length; i++) {
            // generating Random numbers for stations
            int Nbrstationstart = randomGenerator.nextInt(5);
            int Nbrstationend = randomGenerator.nextInt(5);
            // change if passenger is traveling from current station to an other one
            if (Nbrstationstart == Nbrstationend) {
                if (Nbrstationend < 4) {
                    Nbrstationend++;
                } else {
                    Nbrstationend--;
                }
            }
            passengers[i] = new Passenger(bus, stationList.get(Nbrstationstart), stationList.get(Nbrstationend));
            passengers[i].start();
        }
        bus.start();
    }
}

class Passenger extends Thread {
    Bus bus;
    Station station_start, station_end;

    public Passenger(Bus bus, Station s, Station n) {
        this.bus = bus;
        station_start = s;
        station_end = n;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("start station " + station_start.station_id + " end station " + station_end.station_id);
        station_start.waitToGetOnTrain(this); // wait to board train on starting
        // System.out.println(this+"No longer waits and starting to board"); //
        // station
        bus.boardTrain(this); // Board train if space available
        station_end.disembark(this); // Dismebark at destination station
        bus.getOffTrain(this); // Leave Train ( release semaphore)

    }
}

class Bus extends Thread {
    Semaphore semaphore;
    Semaphore busAccess = new Semaphore(1);
    List<Station> stationList;
    Station current_station;
    int boarded = 0, gotoff = 0;

    public Bus(Semaphore semaphore, List<Station> s) {
        this.semaphore = semaphore;
        stationList = s;
    }

    public void boardTrain(Passenger p) {
        if (current_station == p.station_start) {// &&
            // busAccess.availablePermits()==0)
            // {

            // System.out.println("starting to board");
            try {
                // we acquire a new rider in the bus so we take some semaphore
                semaphore.acquire();
                boarded++;
                p.station_start.waiting_to_board--;
                // System.out.println(p.station_start.waiting_to_board+" people
                // left to board");
                System.out.println(boarded + " person(s) boarding");

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

    public void getOffTrain(Passenger p) {
        if (current_station.station_id == p.station_end.station_id) {// &&
            // busAccess.availablePermits()==1)
            // {
            // we release ppl from the bus so we give back some semaphore
            semaphore.release();
            gotoff++;
            boarded--;
            System.out.println(gotoff + " people unboarding ");
        }
    }

    public void setCurrentStation(Station s) {
        current_station = s;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            for (int i = 0; i < stationList.size(); i++) {

                current_station = stationList.get(i);
                System.out.println("Bus arrived at Station :" + i + " and " + current_station.waiting_to_board
                        + " people are waiting");

                // station acquires busAccess here
                current_station.atStation();

                try {

                    // we sleep the bus while we have people to board
                    while ((current_station.waiting_to_board != 0) && (semaphore.availablePermits() > 0)) {
                        // System.out.println("Permit value "
                        // +semaphore.availablePermits());
                        // System.out.println("nbr waiting to board " +
                        // current_station.waiting_to_board);
                        this.sleep(2000);
                    }

                    current_station.waiting_to_board = Math.max(0, (current_station.waiting_to_board - boarded));
                    System.out.println("Number of Passengers boarded the Bus: " + boarded
                            + ", Number of Passengers waiting at Station " + i + " : "
                            + current_station.waiting_to_board);
                    current_station.offStation();
                    System.out.println("Bus go to the next station");

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class Station {
    Bus bus;
    int station_id;
    int waiting_to_board = 0;
    boolean waiting;

    public Station(Bus b, int s, boolean w) {
        station_id = s;
        bus = b;
        waiting = w;
    }

    public void waitToGetOnTrain(Passenger p) {
        waiting_to_board++;
        while (p.station_start != bus.current_station) {
            try {
                p.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    public void atStation() {
        try {
            bus.busAccess.acquire();
            this.startP();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }

    }

    public void startP() {
        waiting = false;
    }

    public void disembark(Passenger p) {
        int test = 0;
        while (bus.current_station.station_id != p.station_end.station_id) {
            // we can go off
            System.out.println("bus at " + bus.current_station.station_id + " station end id for passenger "
                    + this.station_id + " test count " + test);
            test = test + 1;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void setStation(int s) {
        station_id = s;
    }

    public int getStation() {
        return station_id;
    }

    public void offStation() {
        waiting = true;
        bus.busAccess.release();
    }
}
```

I have a problem with the disembarking method. It stay stuck in the while loop. I can't figure out why I'm wrong and what to fix.

Hope to find help here

Shawcs

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Comment: In fact I use the debugger, ok I'm more used to the Visual studio debugger for c# but I still manage to work with this new one. When I enter in the disembark method it sleep my Person thread if you are not at the right station but I don't know why we can't go out. I'm sure that look ridiculous or the solution is easy but still can't find it.

Comment: Your implementation seems to contain several data races. Having the passengers all check the same integer (bus station id) on multiple threads will give you the wrong results. You need to use thread-safe methods to access the station ID, otherwise you might never get the value you want there.